# Delete repeated rows based on column 5 and keep the one with highest value in column 13

Tags: excel, awk

I have a spreadsheet (.csv) with 20 columns and 9000 rows. I want to delete rows that have the same ID in column 5, so I will end up with only one entry (or row) per ID number (unique ID). If there are 2 or more rows with the same ID in column 5, I want to keep the one that has the highest score in column 13. At the same time I want to keep all 20 columns for each row (all the information). Rows with repeated ID and lower score are not important, so I want to just remove those.

I was trying with awk and pearl, but somehow I only manage to do it half way. Let me know if I need to provide more information. Thanks!

INPUT (delimeter=','):

```
geneID, Score, annotation, etc.
ENSG0123, 532.0, intergenic, etc.
ENSG0123, 689.4, 3-UTR, etc.
ENSG0123, 234.0, 5-UTR, etc.
ENSG0399, 567.8, 5-UTR, etc.
```

OUTPUT:

```
geneID, Score, annotation, etc.
ENSG0123, 689.4, 3-UTR, etc.
ENSG0399, 567.8, 5-UTR, etc.
```

Comment: It would be good to see a sample of your input, the corresponding desired output and some details of your attempt. Please [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: improve your code format

Comment: `Let me know if I need to provide more information.` maybe the column 5? and how is your file sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you didn't give the complete input/output example, I guess it was a generic problem. So here is the answer:

```
 sort -t',' -k5,5n -k13,13nr file.csv|awk -F, '!a[$5]++'
```

although awk can do it alone, but with help of `sort` the code could be much easier.  What the above one-liner does:

- sort the file by col5 and col13(numerically, descending)
- pass the sorted result to awk to remove duplicates, base on col5.

here is a little test on it, in the example, col1 is your col5, and col3 is your col13:

```
kent$  cat f
1,2,3
2,8,7
1,2,4
1,4,5
2,2,8
1,3,6
2,2,9
1,2,10
LsyHP 12:38:04 /tmp/test
kent$  sort -t',' -k1,1n -k3,3nr f|awk -F, '!a[$1]++'
1,2,10
2,2,9
```